# Passing a variable into Python from Jinja2 Drop-down menu

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, drop-down-menu, jinja2, webapp2

I'm a programming newbie.  How do I pass a variable from a drop-down menu with Jinja2 templating into my Python 2.7 code?  I'm using the webapp2 framework on Google App Engine.

My code currently looks like this:

```
class AccountNew(Handler):
    def get(self):
        activities = ['Select one', 'Camping', 'Hiking', 'Fishing']
        self.render('account-new.html', activities = activities)

    def post(self):
        acct_name = self.request.get('acct_name')
        activity = self.request.get('activity')
        self.write(acct_name)
        self.write(activity)
```

My Jinja2 template is named "account-new.html" and looks like this:

```
<form method="post">

  <label>
    <div>Account Name</div>
    <input type="text" name="acct_name" value="{{ acct_name }}">
  </label>

  <label>
    <div>Parent</div>
    <select>
      {% for activity in activities %}
          <option value="{{ activity }}">{{ activity }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </label>

  <input type="submit">

</form>
```

The **acct_name** string gets passed back, but the **activity** string seems to come back as an empty string.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have left the 'name' attribute off the select element. Should be like this:

```
<select name="activity">
  {% for activity in activities %}
      <option value="{{ activity }}">{{ activity }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```